# Word VBA: finding red font and give chapter name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I like to search in a part of my document and state the last heading. My document has following structure:

1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 2

   **2.1 sub chapter 1**

   ```
     Table with data
   ```

   **2.2 sub chapter 2**

   ```
     Table with data
   ```

   **2.n sub chapter n**

   ```
     Table with data
   ```
3. Chapter 3

What I like to do is find all red text in one of the tables and find out in which chapter (second level) this is stated.

I tried to define a range for each second level chapter and perform a find within the range. For whatever reason my search is not limited by the range but expands to the end of the document. Therefore any finding of red text in a later chapter will be mistakenly assigned to the first sub chapter.

I also read that limiting the search to a range is kind of buggy (not possible?) due to the dynamic range (frankly something I still don't fully understand). Therefore another approach I could imagine is to search the whole document and just find out the last header before the finding. I just don't know how to approach this.

I would really like a pointer. I keep on reading the same forum posts on this topic but can not get it to work as needed.

Below what I have so far.

**Issues:**

- the first search goes through all sub chapters but the header is still on sub chapter 1
- if there is no red text in a sub chapter the script goes havoc (not quite sure yet what actually happens)

my code so far:

```
Sub find_red_text()

Dim chapter As Range
Dim heading As Range
Dim session As String
Dim counter As Integer

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory ' go to the beginning of the document!
Set heading = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
counter = 0 ' represent level1 headings
Do   ' Loop through headings
    Dim current As Long
    current = heading.Start
    Set heading = heading.GoTo(What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext)
    If heading.Start = current Then
        ' We haven't moved because there are no more headings
        Exit Do
    End If
    If heading.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1 Then
        counter = counter + 1 ' count the level 1 headers
        heading.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
    End If
    If (heading.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel2) And (counter = 2) Then ' special attention to the sub chapter in chapter 2
        heading.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
        session = heading.Text
        Set chapter = heading.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
        With chapter.Find
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchKashida = False
            .MatchDiacritics = False
            .MatchAlefHamza = False
            .MatchControl = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Font.Color = wdColorRed
            Do While .Execute
                chapter.Select ' just for debug purpose
                MsgBox (chapter.Text & " in " & heading)
            Loop
        End With
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Anyone could help me out here? I'm staring at this for some time, go nuts by reading the same "solutions" out there but it just don't do what I need it to do...

Comment: please explain what is meant by "goes havoc".

Comment: Essentially the found text is copied to another area of the document. But it appears when there are no findings in a chapter it repeats to write old text (e.g. previous one). I could explain it (e.g. writes again the variables still containing the old content) but it does that multiple times. Later one is the part I do not understand and cannot identify a pattern (why it writes it ~30 times even yet there are only 10 chapters).

Answer (score 1):

As usual: less is more.
I managed to solve it by removing a bit of clutter and search the whole document and just limit the action to the section where I want it to happen.

Below is my revised code which works like a charm

```
Sub find_red_text()

Dim rng As Range
Dim endrange As Integer
Dim session As Range

endrange = 0 ' will be written with the end of the range (count of characters) to see if the range has changed or remain the same

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory ' go to the beginning of the document!
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)

With rng.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop 'wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Font.Color = wdColorRed '255
    Do While .Execute
        If rng.Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber) = 2 Then 'only consider second column which is the findings!
            Set session = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious)
            session.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
            If (endrange = rng.End) Then 'no change in the end of the range, therefore we have finished the search!
                Exit Do
            Else ' keep going and push the endrange value out
                endrange = rng.End
            End If
            msgbox (rng.text & " in " & session.text)
        End If
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

**Main changes needed:**

1) I tried a different approach 
from: select a chapter and search within 
to: search the whole document and filter findings based on chapter

2) the havoc happened because I reached the end of the document with the search. The end position of my search result never changed anymore. Therefore I track the end of the range and if it's not increasing anymore I stop the search/loop.

Now working like a charm :)